# Nested routing without changing part of UI flutter

Tags: flutter, user-interface, routes, nested-routes

I want to create Nested routing without changing part of UI
In the image i want to change the route of B portion only. 'B' can have multiple routes like after clicking to B, screen should change to  B1 then B2 and so on and while doing this the Portion A should not change. How can i achieve this?
Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify you question. What to you mean by "i want to route only B portion"?

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/effects/nested-nav

Comment: @Dani3le_ question updated please check.

Comment: @pskink i referred the link but in that whole screen is changing

Comment: Oh ok, now I understand. At first glance I think you could create a Container (on part B) that changes it's content based on user interaction. For example, by having a stateful widget you could save all Container's (B) widgets in a variable and then update it whenever you need with the new content you want to display.

Comment: no, only changing part is where `Navigator` is placed - in another words: if you have `Column` with two children: `Text` and `Navigator` only the bottom part changes

Comment: @Dani3le_ the solution u are proposing good but let suppose i have 5 screen(pages) inside that B(B1,B2,B3) which appears in a sequential manner after clicking some button
B1 contains some data, B2 also contains and so on. but at some point  it will be terrible to manage i guess.

Comment: That's true, but not knowing how may nested routes you had to make this was the first thing I thought of.

Comment: @pskink ok let me check that again properly

Comment: @Dani3le_ ohh its ok.  i have max 4 to 5 with lists, data, states, widgets etc. Thanks

Comment: @pskink i have implanted it but whenevr i am moving back all the screens destroys
i want the process to be like if i moved B1 to B2 and after pressing back it should come to B1

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example,

This is the page you want to keep at the bottom part

```
class AnotherView extends StatelessWidget {
  const AnotherView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {...}
}
```

---

In your current structure keep the instance of type `Widget` at bottom

```
Widget dynamicContent = Center(child: Text("B"));

...

Column(
  children: [
    Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.white)),

    Expanded(child: Container(color: Colors.pink, child: dynamicContent)),
  ],
)
```

And to change content, use like `dynamicContent = AnotherView()`